# Error Handling with Cursor in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have cursor which either Update table or Add data if record don't exist. My requirement is

```
OPEN CURSOR
     Fetch Next
        While @@fetch_status = 0
          if (Record found) then 
              call update stored procedure
          else
              call Add stored procedure
```

Now, issue I am having is, both update/add stored procedure call multiple other stored procedures to do operation. If anything wrong with any other stored procedure, I need to rollback everything

I did try with `Begin Transaction` and checking if `@@Error` but it didn't work.

Any help? I am using SQL Server 2008

Comment: `begin try` all sql to run here `end try begin catch` all error logic here `end catch`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Open Cursor
 Fetch Next
        While @@fetch_status = 0
          BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRANSACTION
          if (Record found) then Call update Store proc
          else
                  Call Add store proc

          Commit transaction
          End try
          Begin Catch
             if @@Trancount > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
          END CATCH
 FETCH NEXT
```