# Keep Stored Procedure running even if there is error

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that needs to run even there are some errors. SO here a small exameple

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FirstProcedure
@SomeParams 

AS BEGIN


Declare Db_Cursor Cursor For
Select * From #TmpR
Open Db_Cursor
Fetch Next From Db_cursor Into 
@SomaValues
While @@Fetch_Status = 0 
    Begin
    set @ERR = 0 
    exec [SecondProcedure] @SomaValues
    set @ERR = @@ERROR

    if @ERR <> 0 begin
       -- do some things in case of error 
     end
    Fetch Next From Db_Cursor Into 
@SomaValues

    End

END
```

In case the second procedure returns and error i catch it the @ERR variable and do some other things, but I want the cursor to run till the end of the table, as it's not very important if 2-3 rows from 100.000 can't be inserting using the SecondProcedure ?

What can I do?

Comment: if you expect there could be an error in the second stored proc, put some defensive code that performs a check before the error is hit and only execute the code if it's safe.

Comment: What errors are you expecting?

Comment: Inserting null in not nullable columns, truncated string and so on.

Comment: @Tanner that would be an option, but I would rather not do it, as in SomeValues there could be about 150 fields, I would rather not check 150 fields but let MS SQL decide if the row can be inserted or not.

Comment: You mean like a try catch as in: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to continue cursor loop even error occured in the loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893741/how-to-continue-cursor-loop-even-error-occured-in-the-loop) - you just need to add `try catch` blocks to the code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065213/error-handling-with-cursor-in-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `Try/Catch`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FirstProcedure
@SomeParams 

AS BEGIN


Declare Db_Cursor Cursor For
Select * From #TmpR
Open Db_Cursor
Fetch Next From Db_cursor Into 
@SomaValues
While @@Fetch_Status = 0 
  Begin
    begin try
       exec [SecondProcedure] @SomaValues
    end try
    begin catch
      SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
            ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
            ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
            ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
            ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
            ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
    end catch

    Fetch Next From Db_Cursor Into @SomaValues
  End
  close db_cursor
  deallocate db_cursor

END
```

Comment: For some reason it still stops and throws error. I'll try it again.

Comment: how many columns #tmpr has? also you need close and deallocate too. (I edit my answer for this one)

Comment: the error might be for other lines of code. would you update your question and add the error you get